# Помогите объяснить механизм nextSibling в XML

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

У меня есть эта иерархия XML:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как вы можете видеть:

```
r.firstChild возвращает a;
```

Но я не знаю - какой элемент вернется в:

```
a.nextSibling
```

И я не знаю - какой элемент вернет следующий результат из предыдущего результата.

Спасибо!

Comment: Сиблинг - это тот кто на том же уровне после `a`, то есть `b`. А для `b` nextSibling - это `с`.  Сиблинги, по русски говоря, - это "родные братья и сестры", то есть те кто в дереве на одном уровне с элементом и имеют общего родителя.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо **@u-mulder**

> Сиблинг - это тот кто на том же уровне после a, то есть b. А для b
> nextSibling - это с. Сиблинги, по русски говоря, - это "родные братья
> и сестры", то есть те кто в дереве на одном уровне с элементом и имеют
> общего родителя.